# Close FancyBox that is inside an iframe from the parent page onload

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, fancybox

I know this is possible and can be done, or at least used to be like that.

Now I can't find the code anywhere.

I want to close the fancybox within the iframe on document ready from the parent page.

How to do this? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Are they on the same domain? Otherwise you won't be able to

Comment: No they're not. And you're right, that's probably why none of my codes have worked :| Thanks for clearing that up!

Comment: Haha yeah, no problem. If they are on the same domain, you're pretty free to do what you want. Otherwise, browsers don't allow it because it's a security issue (gaining access to manipulate anyone else's page probably isn't good)

Comment: @Ian The page inside the Iframe sets a cookie after the fancybox is closed for the first time and doesn't show it in next visits. is it possible to check for that cookie and set it if it is not already set?

Comment: I don't think so. Again, if they're in different domains, they can't share cookies. Is that what you mean? One page set the cookie, the other one read it? Otherwise, if you're talking about one page setting a cookie and then checking/getting it again later (even at a different page session), then that should be fine.

Comment: I want to set the cookie from my own site but for the other site, but the way you describe it that also seems not doable.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately that shouldn't work either. Otherwise you could steal other people's cookie information (like session IDs) and impersonate them. Just another security breach precaution =/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After careful examination and researching everywhere from here to all over Google, seems like this is not possible at all due to security issues rising from it if the browsers did allow such a thing.